# show the xy data point when the mouse over over the data point

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to show the data point (x value, y value) of a graph when hover to a specific data point.
does anyone know how to achieve it based on my current code?

```
        ax = df.plot(x=1, y=2)  #x value from column 1 of pandas dataframe, 
                                #y value from column 2 of pandas dataframe
```

my graph look something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to achive this using `bokeh`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from collections import OrderedDict


x = np.sort(np.random.rand(15))
y = np.sort(np.random.rand(15))
names = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"))

p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=600,
           tools="pan,hover", 
           title="Changes",
           x_axis_label='height', 
           y_axis_label='Weight',
           toolbar_location="left"
          )

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = OrderedDict([('height', '@x'), ('Weight', '$y')])

output_notebook()

p.line(x, y, legend="Weight")
p.line(x, y, legend="Height", line_color="red")

show(p)
```

gives

[image]